# How to install Moodle for a homepage?

Tags: 14.04, webserver, moodle

I am installing **`moodle 2.9.3`** on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. How do I get to my default Moodle page?

These are the instructions:

> Open a web browser and navigate to your server. Append `/moodle` onto the end of your server address (i.e. `technerdservices.ddns.net/moodle`).

How do I find my server name like the example. I am following instructions from [this web page: How to install Moodle on Ubuntu](http://blog.technerdservices.com/index.php/2015/05/tutorial-how-to-install-moodle-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

When you use you own desktop that adress tends to be "http://localhost" or "https://localhost" if you also activated SSL. Have a look in the hosts file on your system with ...

```
more /etc/hosts
```

I would expect you to have only 'localhost' here.  If not read on ...

If you have your desktop open to the world and this is intended for usages by 'others' on the web that visit your desktop this can also be "http://{your_external_ip_adress}" and when you bought a website address it will be "http://{website_address}".

You are suppose to add "/moodle" to the one that applies to you. I would expect "http://localhost/moodle".